# UrlRefferer vs. url as a POST parameter taken from document.URL

Tags: javascript, c#, iis

We wrote a pixel js that the client supposed to implement in his website.
His website send a post request to my Web Server (iis).

The point is that I need to extract the url of the website sending the request (the referrer).

Which method is more better? and reliable?
1. Extracting the Request.UrlRefferer
2. Send the url as Post parameter taken from document.URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UrlRefferer` will work fine in most cases. If this is an Intranet application, or it's external but you own the client(s) too, that option will be fine. It may not be reliable in the sense that it could be stripped by a proxy or another tool between the browser and your server.

If you have reason to believe the `UrlReferrer` header will be stripped then sending the URL as a parameter from the client is a good backup.

Comment: What do you mean by owing the client? I dont owe my customer website, and basically I don't know nothing about the referrer websites.

Comment: I meant whether or not you have control over the client code. It sounds like you do not. If it's absolutely essential that you get the client's URL, you may have to require that the client send it to you with the request. Otherwise, if you're okay with only getting it most of the time, just reading `UrlReferrer` should work fine.